# XSLT List View Web Part in crosslist mode?

Tags: xlv, sharepoint-designer

SharePoint Foundation - Is there a way to use the new XSLT List View Web Part to aggregate content from multiple lists?

I am able to do it with a Data View Web Part, but I'd rather do it in a XLV Web Part as it is the go-forward tool.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out? So how to aggregate more lists to one xsltlistviewwebpaart and possibly do subview. Thx

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible with the XLV webpart.

Answer (score 0):

HI,

You can create view on multiple lists very easily in sharepoint designer.
Below link explains in detail about the same.

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-Performing_joins_between_SharePoint_lists.aspx

Rajat.

Comment: Rajat - Thanks, but my question was specifically about the XLV Web Part. As I said, I know that it can be done with Data View Web Parts.